# SQL query to have data in field instead of new record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have searched for this but I'm probably using the wrong terminology.

The following query

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.entry FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID 
WHERE t2.meta_key IN ('wp_x1','wp_x2');
```

Returns data similar to below where there are 2 records for each of the `meta_key` fields

```
name1,wp_x1_entry
name1,wp_x2_entry
name2,wp_x1_entry
name2,wp_x2_entry
```

How do I amend the query to return this instead?

```
name1,wp_x1_entry,wp_x2_entry
name2,wp_x1_entry,wp_x2_entry
```

The table/field names have been changed to hide sensitive info. Also, I know these are badly designed tables but I am unable to change the db structure.

This will be calling a mySql db from C# code.

Comment: You need to use the `group_concat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join another time with t2, looking for wp_x2 only

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.entry, t3.entry
FROM t1
  JOIN t2       ON t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.meta_key = 'wp_x1'
  JOIN t2 as t3 ON t3.ID = t1.ID and t3.meta_key = 'wp_x2'
```

Will return only rows with both wp_x1 and wp_x2. Use LEFT_JOIN if one/none is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Group By t1.name and group_concat t2.entry.

like this :

```
SELECT t1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.entry) FROM t1 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID 
WHERE t2.meta_key IN ('wp_x1','wp_x2')
GROUP BY t1.name;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html